# How to create a python object that be passed to be open as a file

Tags: python, file

I have some lines in Python that I want to pass a function that for some reason only accepts inputs as filepaths. For the example, let's call this function `func.read()`.

Since `func.read()` only knows how to reads files, not strings directly, I'm being forced to write my text into an auxiliary file and then pass the file path to `func.read()`:

```
text="""some
random
text"""
fout = open("aux","wt")
fout.write(text)
fout.close()
func.read("aux")
```

But this is a hassle, and I'd like to avoid relying on writing external files. I could modify the function to take a string or list of strings, but this is a last case scenario (for some other reasons I can't go into detail here).

Is there a way I can "trick" this function by creating an object that behaves like a path to a file? Essentially an object that can be passed to `open()` I'd say.

Cheers

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want exactly.  Are you trying to take `text` in your example and pass it around somewhere?

Comment: @kevin628 I'm trying to pass `text` to `func.read`, but `func.read` only takes a file path, not a string. So I have to write my string into a file and then pass the path of that file to `func.read`. I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Yes, there is a way.  I'll write up an answer here shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).  You can make an object that looks like a file object.

Because you only really need the `read()` method of a file object, you can make a class that also has a `read()` method on it.  Simply create an instance of the class and pass it to the code dependent on `read()`. Whatever that dependent code is will be oblivious to the fact that you gave it a "fake" file object.

Here's an example.

```
class FileImitator:
    def __init__(self, contents_of_file):
        self.contents_of_file = contents_of_file

    def read(self):
        return self.contents_of_file
```

And here's a function that is expecting a file object, but I will give it an instance of my `FileImitator` instead:

```
def read_from_file(file):
    print(file.read())

imitation_file = FileImitator("Great Scott!")

read_from_file(imitation_file)  # prints "Great Scott!"
```

Of course, if I wanted to give it a real file object, I could do that, too:

```
def read_from_file(file):
    print(file.read())

real_file = open("/tmp/favorite-quotes.txt", "r")

read_from_file(real_file)  # prints out the contents of "favorite-quotes.txt"
```

Comment: What am I missing? when I paste the first two boxes i get this error:

"    print(file.read())
TypeError: read() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: @KyleSwanson Don't pass any arguments to `read()` when you call it.  The `read()` method doesn't take any parameters.

Comment: @KyleSwanson Actually, try the first two boxes again, as I have updated the code.

Comment: @kevin628 thanks for the attempt, but I don't need an object that has a `.read()` method, I need one that can be passed to an `open()` function! Such as `open(imitation_file)`. So I could read it with `open(imitation_file).read()`.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, then, because `open()` only takes a string.  There's no way to change what `open()` takes.